# Frequently getting "localhost not found" error in Vite React project, and the project started once but my JS elements didn't show up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I'm consistently encountering a "localhost not found" error in a project I'm developing using Vite and React. I've tried changing the port, but the issue persists. Additionally, I managed to start the project once, but at that time, my JavaScript elements were not visible on the page.

What can I do to resolve this issue? What steps should I follow, or what configurations in my project should I check?

The steps I've taken so far include:

Changing the port
Updating dependencies
Checking project configuration files
However, these steps haven't resolved the issue. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Edit: when i use npm run build  i'm getting this error

```js
Could not resolve entry module "index.html".
error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "index.html".
    at error (file:///C:/Users/lcyke/OneDrive/Masa%C3%BCst%C3%BC/Chatbot/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:337:30)
    at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (file:///C:/Users/lcyke/OneDrive/Masa%C3%BCst%C3%BC/Chatbot/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:17990:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

Comment: you trying to run netwrok "fetch" on files (file:// url), place it to some webserver (http or https url) and it shall work